# Correctly determining if an IList<int> already exists in IList<IList<int>>

Tags: c#

I'm using 3 iterators to iterate through an int[] object to find lists containing three int's that all sum to 0, without adding duplicate lists to the final return object. Once the iterators find a valid sequence, each array value that the iterator points to is added to a temporary IList object via syntax such as "tempList.Add(nums[a]);" e.t.c. This tempList is then added to the final IList<IList> return object.

To check for duplicates, I'm using the following sytax:

```
if ((nums[c] + nums[a] + nums[b] == 0) && !answerList.Contains(tempList))

{
    answerList.Add(tempList);
}
```

This works when the IList<IList> is initially empty, however the second clause evaluated "false" for the following scenario, which is preventing the valid tempList from being added to the IList<IList> answerList :

```
IList<IList<int>> == [[-1,0,1]]
tempList == [-1,-1,2]
```

Do I need to extend a Comparable interface to correct this? I've double checked the array values for a, b and c and they collectively sum to 0, so I'm certain that it's the .Contains comparison that is causing issue.

Here is the code:

```
 public IList<IList<int>> ThreeSum(int[] nums) // maybe use three index pointers to fill triplet, one starting at index 0, one
                                                      // starting at index nums.Lenght - 1 and one starting near or at middle
                                                      // 5 billion possible combinations of triplets among array of 3001 triplets
        {
            IList<int> tempList = new List<int>();
            IList<IList<int>> answerList = new List<IList<int>>();
            int countPositive = 0;
            int countNegative = 0;
            bool addAnswerList = false;
            int indexPositive = 0;
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int c = 0;
            bool aExtreme = false;
            bool bExtreme = false;
            bool cExtreme = false;
            
                

            if (nums == null)
                return answerList;

            if (nums.Length == 0 /* || /* nums.Length < 3 */)
                return answerList;

            if (nums.Length == 1 && nums[0] == 0)
                return answerList;

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++) // corner case where all array values are either postive or negative
                                                  // 0 sum triplet not possible
            {
                if (nums[i] > 0)
                    countPositive++;
                else if (nums[i] < 0)
                    countNegative++;    
            }

            if ((countPositive == nums.Length || countNegative == nums.Length) || (countNegative == 0 && countPositive == 0))
                return answerList;

            if (nums.Length < 51)
            {
                int temp = 0;
                
                for (int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++) // use recursive sort to go through 3001 elements, use linear if less than 51
                {
                    temp = nums[i];
                    int j = i;

                    while (j > 0 && nums[j-1] > temp)
                    {
                        nums[j] = nums[j-1];
                        j--;
                    }
                    
                    nums[j] = temp; 
                   
                }
               
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", nums));

            }

            

             else if (nums.Length > 50) // recursive sort for larger input array
            {
                mergeSort(nums);
            }

            // Now nums is storted, 0 sum triplet will most likely be found where entries change from negative to positive
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                if (nums[i] > 0)
                {
                  //  toPositive = true;
                    indexPositive = i;
                    break;
                }
                
            }

            Console.WriteLine(indexPositive);


            if (indexPositive == 0) // case to make sure accessors do not get invalid number
            {
                 a = 0;          // initialize other two index accessors in addition to indexPositive
                 b = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                 a = indexPositive - 1; // initialize other two index accessors in addition to indexPositive
                 b = indexPositive - 1;
            }

            c = indexPositive; // store initial indexPositive value into variable c as indexPositive will change
                               // throughtout the interation
            
            // if indexPositive is less than (nums.Length / 2), iterate two other accessors towards end of nums
            // else, interate two other accessors towards nums[0]

            if (c < (nums.Length / 2)) // use iterator c in place of indexPositive
            {
                while (c < nums.Length && b < nums.Length && a >= 0)
                {

                    if (a == 0 || a == nums.Length - 3)
                    {
                        aExtreme = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        aExtreme = false;
                    }

                    if (b == 1 || b == nums.Length - 2)
                    {
                        bExtreme = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bExtreme = false;
                    }

                    if (c == 2 || c == nums.Length - 1)
                    {
                        cExtreme = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cExtreme = false;
                    }

                    if ((c != a && c != b && a != b) && (nums[c] + nums[a] + nums[b] == 0)) // if nums add to 0, add them to tempList
                    {
                        tempList.Add(nums[a]);
                        tempList.Add(nums[b]);
                        tempList.Add(nums[c]);
                    }

                   
                    
                    // need to check if exact triplet is duplicate or if tempList triplet contains same 3 values in different order
                    // 3 values in different order not an issues since input list is already sorted!!!!
                    // but need to be aware order accessors are added to temp list. Accessors cannot "crossover" one another!!!
                    if ((nums[c] + nums[a] + nums[b] == 0) && !answerList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(tempList)) /*!answerList.Contains(tempList)*/)
                        // Having issues, answerList.Contains does not currently do what is desired
                    {
                        answerList.Add(tempList);  // add tempList to answerList 
                        addAnswerList = true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        addAnswerList = false;
                    }

                    tempList.Clear();          // clear tempList to prepare for next entry

                    // Make changes here to make sure only 1 accessor iterates at a time, to check all possible and logical combinations
                    // Since array is now sorted, iteration towards sums[0] only has to continue if sum of 3 accessors is greater than 0
                    // Once active accessor returns a value that results in 0 sum, further iteration is guaranteed to return
                    // an identical triplet or one that sums to less than 0. At this point, the two accessors that are going in the same
                    // direction should be iterated by 1 position and the cycle repeated
                    
                    

                    if (nums[a] + nums[b] + nums[c] < 0) // still have chance to get to 0 value triplet with rightmost accessor
                                                                                   
                    {
                        c++;
                    }


                    else if ((addAnswerList == true) || nums[a] + nums[b] + nums[c] > 0) // no point in further iteration,
                                                                                         // reset 'c' accessor to original starting
                                                                                        // position and decrement other accessors by 1
                                                                                        // towards first array element
                    {                                                                   // to begin cycle again
                        c = indexPositive - 1;
                        b--;
                        a--;
                    }

                }
                
            }

            else  // a and b accessors are interated towards 0
            {
                while (c < nums.Length && a >= 0 && b >= 0)
                {
                    if (a == 0 || a == nums.Length - 3)
                    {
                        aExtreme = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        aExtreme = false;
                    }

                    if (b == 1 || b == nums.Length - 2)
                    {
                        bExtreme = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bExtreme = false;
                    }

                    if (c == 2 || c == nums.Length - 1)
                    {
                        cExtreme = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cExtreme = false;
                    }


                    if ((c != a && c != b && a != b) && (nums[c] + nums[a] + nums[b] == 0))  // if nums add to 0, add them to tempList 
                                                                                                                                 // need to check if exact triplet is duplicate
                    {
                        tempList.Add(nums[a]);
                        tempList.Add(nums[b]);
                        tempList.Add(nums[c]);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", tempList));

                    

                    // need to check if exact triplet is duplicate or if tempList triplet contains same 3 values in different order
                    // 3 values in different order not an issues since input list is already sorted!!!!
                    // but need to be aware order accessors are added to temp list. Accessors cannot "crossover" one another!!!
                    if ((nums[c] + nums[a] + nums[b] == 0) && !answerList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(tempList)))
                    // Having issues, answerList.Contains does not currently do what is desired
                    {
                        answerList.Add(tempList);  // add tempList to answerList 
                        addAnswerList=true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        addAnswerList = false;
                    }

                    tempList.Clear();          // clear tempList to prepare for next entry

                    // Make changes here to make sure only 1 accessor iterates at a time, to check all possible and logical combinations
                    // Since array is now sorted, iteration towards sums[0] only has to continue if sum of 3 accessors is greater than 0
                    // Once active accessor returns a value that results in 0 sum, further iteration is guaranteed to return
                    // an identical triplet or one that sums to less than 0. At this point, the two accessors that are going in the same
                    // direction should be iterated by 1 position and the cycle repeated
                    
                    
                    if (nums[a] + nums[b] + nums[c] > 0) // still have chance to get to 0 value triplet with
                                                                                    // leftmost accessor
                    {
                        a--;
                    }
                    

                    else if ((addAnswerList == true) || nums[a] + nums[b] + nums[c] < 0) // no point in further iteration,
                                                                                         // reset 'a' accessor to original starting
                                                                                        // position and increment other accessors by 1
                                                                                        // towards last array element
                    {                                                                   // to begin cycle again
                        a = b; // a = indexPositive - 1;

                        if ((bExtreme == false && b < nums.Length - 2) && (cExtreme == false && c < nums.Length - 1)) 
                            // if there is still room to run towards end of array, increment, else decrement
                        {
                            b++;
                            c++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bExtreme = true;
                            cExtreme = true;
                            a -= 2;
                            b--;

                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", answerList));
            return answerList;  
            
           
        }

        public void merge(int[] array1, int[] array2, int[] outArray)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            while (i + j < outArray.Length)
            {
                if (j == array2.Length || (i < array1.Length && (array1[i] < array2[j])))
                {
                    outArray[i + j] = array1[i++];
                }

                else
                {
                    outArray[i + j] = array2[j++];
                }
            }
        }

        public void mergeSort(int[] inputArray)
        {
            if (inputArray.Length < 2)
                return;

            int[] firstHalf = new int[inputArray.Length / 2];
            int[] secondHalf = new int[inputArray.Length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < (inputArray.Length / 2); i++)
            { 
                firstHalf[i] = inputArray[i]; 
            }

            for (int i = inputArray.Length / 2; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
            {
                secondHalf[i] = inputArray[i];
            }

            mergeSort(firstHalf);
            mergeSort(secondHalf);  
            
            merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, inputArray);

        }
```

Comment: The `.Contains` method will check via default comparison, which is reference comparison. Meaning two new list instances will be nonequal, even when they have same elements pointwise. It seems that you want to check whether `answerList` contains an "equivalent" (or "sequentially equal") list. The problem is that the default list won't let you do that. You may want to utilize `HashSet` instead (which will be faster anyway) with a custom `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

`answerList.Contains(tempList))`

which checks only for reference equality, with

`answerList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(tempList))`

which will run *SequenceEqual* on the *answerList* until it finds the first answer that has the same integer elements and returns false if none can be found.

Keep in mind that these functions require *System.Linq*.

**Credit:** thanks Hans Keﬆing for suggesting *Any(...)* over *FirstOrDefault(...) != null*

Comment: gabrieliussla, I added using System.Linq to my project and changed the code to ` answerList.Find(x => x.SequenceEqual(tempList)) == null `, however I then get a CS1061 error which says "`IList<IList<int>>` does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no accessible extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type '`IList<IList<int>>`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: gabrieliussla, I added using System.Linq to my project and changed the code to `answerList.Find(x => x.SequenceEqual(tempList)) == null`, however I then get a CS1061 error which says '`IList<IList<int>>`' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no accessible extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type '`IList<IList<int>>`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You are right, *IList* does not implement *Find*. Try *Linq*'s *FirstOrDefault* instead.

Comment: Instead of `.FirstOrDefault(...)!=null`, you can also use `.Any(..)` - returns true when there is at least one match

Comment: Hans, I changed the statement to ' !answerList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(tempList)) ' and  I still can't get tempList ==  [-1, -1, 2] added to the answerList

Comment: Also to clarify, while stepping through ' if ((nums[c] + nums[a] + nums[b] == 0) && !answerList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(tempList))) ' shows up as "AnonymousMethod_1 returned true" in the Locals watch box, however with the next step the program moves to the "else" case and does not add tempList to answerList

Comment: @jlakes85, it's hard to tell what is going wrong without seeing more of the code

Comment: @gabrieliussla, please see the entire code below:

Comment: @jlakes85 I tried to run your code, but it seems like there are problems with the rest of the logic. With [-3, 0, 1, 4, 3, 2], ```nums[c] + nums[a] + nums[b] == 0``` was never satisfied. With [-1, -1, -2, -3, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2] it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: gabrielliussla, that's the point I stopped at while trying to determine why once [-1, -1, 2] was selected by the iterators, it was not being added to the list of lists. If that gets resolved, the program will being to iterate properly again

Comment: It is being added to the list of lists, I just printed out the value of answerList and it has [-1, -1, -2] in there. It still keeps looping though, so that's a problem with some other part of the code.